# Error: $injector:modulerr Module Error while Upgrade AngularJs 1.5 to Angular Js 1.8.2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm upgrading "angular" : "1.5.0" to "angular" : "1.8.2" .
Followed multiple articles and opinions but still got the same error as I mention below in the snapshot.

And getting error. :  Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]

Error: $injector:modulerr
Module Error
Failed to instantiate module app due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr]
[image]
[image]

I have just upgraded as recommended both angularjs version should be same for the required dependencies below

```
from "angular" : "1.5.0" to "angular" : "1.8.2"
from "angular-cookies" : "1.5.0" to "angular-cookies" : "1.8.2"
from "angular-sanitize" : "1.5.0" to "angular-sanitize" : "1.8.2"
from "angular-ui-router" : "0.2.15" to "angular-ui-router" : "1.0.30"
from "ui-router-extras" : "0.0.14" to "ui-router-extras" : "0.1.3"
```

Here is my bower dependency

```
{
"name" : "app",
"version" : "1.0.0",
"dependencies" : {
"angular-i18n" : "1.4.7",
"bootstrap" : "3.3.5",
"font-awesome" : "4.5.0",
"angular" : "1.8.2",
"codemirror" : "5.19.0",
"angular-animate": "1.5.0",
"angular-bootstrap" : "0.13.3",
"angular-cookies" : "1.8.2",
"angular-dashboard-framework" : "0.10.0",
"Sortable" : "1.2.1",
"angular-dynamic-locale" : "0.1.27",
"angular-resource" : "1.5.0",
"angular-sanitize" : "1.8.2",
"angular-translate" : "2.8.1",
"angular-ui-grid" : "4.0.6",
"angular-ui-router" : "1.0.30",
"jquery" : "3.6.0",
"jsTimezoneDetect" : "1.0.5",
"moment" : "latest",
"moment-timezone" : "0.5.11",
"ng-idle" : "1.1.0",
"oclazyload" : "1.0.6",
"ui-router-extras" : "0.1.3",

"angular-mocks" : "1.5.0",
"moment-duration-format" : "1.3.0",

"ng-grid" : "2.0.13",
"ng-table" : "0.3.2",

"ace-builds":"1.3.1",
"angular-ui-ace" : "0.2.1",

"ng-table-resizable-columns" : "latest",
"angular-xeditable" : "0.1.9",
"jquery-ui": "1.10.4",

"angular-ui-sortable" : "0.13.4",
"angular-ui-sortable-multiselection" : "0.3.1",
"angular-ui-utils" : "0.1.1",
"angular-selection-model" : "0.7.0",
"angular-ui-codemirror" : "0.3.0",
"ng-context-menu" : "1.0.1",
"angular-typeahead" : "0.2.0",
"angular-elastic" : "2.3.5",
"angular-jquery-dialog-service" : "0.8.1",
"ng-file-upload" : "12.0.4",
"zip.js" : "36f9f96",

"spin.js" : "2.0.1",
"jquery.loadmask.spin" : "1.2.0",
"angular-http-auth" : "1.2.1",
"angular-chosen-localytics" : "1.0.6",

"js-beautify" : "1.5.5",
"angular-tree-control": "0.2.9",
"angular-hovercard": "1.0.3",
"d3" : "3.5.5",
"d3-tip" : "0.6.7",
"angular-utf8-base64" : "0.0.5", 

"mobile-angular-ui" : "1.2.0-rc.3",
"angular-touch": "1.5.0",
"lunr.js" : "0.5.4",
"jsondiffpatch" : "0.1.22",

"angular-google-chart" : "0.0.11",
"qtip2" : "latest"
 },

"resolutions" : {
"jquery": "3.6.0",
"angular": "1.8.2",
"angular-mocks": "1.5.0",
"ace-builds":"1.3.1",
"angular-ui-router": "1.0.30"
}
}
```

Comment: `phoenix.core` dependency is not being resolved properly. Check if you have included phoenix's angularjs file

Comment: I have mentioned the upgraded dependency.
And I feel the error information is misleading, I tried adding ngRoute in the module but could not succeed.